How do I scrape the websites where the source code is just a wall of javascript and none of the text in the website is available on the website?
I am trying to scrape the webpage of the UCLA faculty for a personal project.
https://samueli.ucla.edu/search-faculty/#cs
How do I get the data of the webpage when none of the data is visible in the source code?
I am using beautifulsoup to web scrape the website. I cannot figure out how to get the names and other data when none of it is visible.

another question closed prematurely?! there's an ajax endpoint to get the body html containing all the data
